# Is it possible to stream video from https:// (e.g. YouTube) into python with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, video, youtube

[This link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) has a tidy little example of how to use python's OpenCV library, `cv2` to stream data from a camera into your python shell. I'm looking to do some experiments and would like to use the following YouTube video feed: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCUqsPLvYBQ`.

I've tried adapting the example as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCUqsPLvYBQ')

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Which produces the error:

```
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCUqsPLvYBQ
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/opencv20160107-29960-t5glvv/opencv-2.4.12/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 261
```

Is there a simple fix that would allow me to stream this video feed into my python shell via `cv2`? Not absolutely committed to `cv2`, either, if there are other libraries out there that will accomplish the same purpose.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to open `VideoCapture` like this. In openCV documentation on [videocapture](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a949d90b766ba42a6a93fe23a67785951) is written that the argument should be a file. But you can use [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) in between.

Comment: @incBrain: this looks promising, thanks. will check it out ASAP and let you know.

Comment: @incBrain: `youtube-dl` was the way to go. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you need to have 2 things installed

1. pafy (pip install pafy)
2. youtube_dl (sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl)

after installing these two packages you can use the youtube url to play the streaming videos from youtube.
Please refer the code below

```py
url = 'https://youtu.be/W1yKqFZ34y4'
vPafy = pafy.new(url)
play = vPafy.getbest(preftype="webm")

#start the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(play.url)
while (True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    """
    your code here
    """
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break    

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Right on, thanks. It's been ages since I asked this question. Could someone please test this and confirm that it works so that I can select the answer??

Comment: It is working as I have pasted the working code from my script. you can also try it.

Comment: Not Working, using opencv 3.4.0

Comment: @ArjunKava Do you found way to fix this issue?

Comment: Nope, @wownis. I had downloaded a video stream in the chunk and then used video capture.

Comment: How is this accepted as an answer VideoCapture() accepts only filenames according to documentation and any youtube stream url just returns nothing.

Comment: IOError: ERROR: W1yKqFZ34y4: "token" parameter not in video info for unknown reason; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its com
plete output.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv-suite_1535558553474/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Comment: Check whether your pafy is working correctly or not. It should return a video stream
(https://pythonhosted.org/Pafy/ ) 

also check the prefered type argument it can have different values as mentioned below :
preftype (str) – Preferred type, set to mp4, webm, flv, 3gp or any

Comment: @ArjunKava the solution is to upgrade your openCV version :-)

Comment: try play = vPafy.getbest(preftype="mp4") instead of play = vPafy.getbest(preftype="webm")

Answer (score 3):

it is possible with pafy (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pafy)

```
import cv2, pafy

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKX8uaoy9c8"
videoPafy = pafy.new(url)
best = videoPafy.getbest(preftype="webm")

video=cv2.VideoCapture(best.url)
```

Comment: This doesn't work (at least with OpenCV 3.4.0). video.read() returns always (False, None). The url is valid, e.g. wget would download the video.

Comment: @burny 
You found a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

@incBrain's suggestion to download the youtube video to local mp4 was the way to go here. Here were the steps that I used to set up a remote server environment on EC2, with output piped into my local computer via X11 forwarding:

- `ssh -X -i "<ssh_key.pem>" ubuntu@<IP-address>.compute-1.amazonaws.com` (Note the `-X` option is an important addition here. It's what we use to pass output from the EC-2 server to a local X11 client)
- `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl` (I know, `sudo pip` is bad. I blame the site instructions)
- Download youtube video to local file: `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUjF1fRw9sA -o motocross.mp4`
- [`python demo_cv.py`](https://gist.github.com/aaronpolhamus/a5219b1c36e41332b4cc328a5ff016e2)

X11 forwarding can be tricky. If you run into any hangups there [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663127/how-to-run-py-faster-rcnn-with-x11-forwarding) might be helpful to you also.

Comment: Is it possible to access it as a stream? Instead of having to wait for the file to download.

Comment: Also, we have legal constraints that disallows us from actually downloading the file and requires us to use streaming only.

Answer (score 2):

I've added Youtube URL source support in my [VidGear](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Python Library that automatically pipelines YouTube Video into OpenCV by providing its URL only. Here is a complete python example:

#### For VidGear `v0.1.9` below:

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
import cv2

stream = CamGear(source='https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ', y_tube = True, logging=True).start() # YouTube Video URL as input

# infinite loop
while True:
    
    frame = stream.read()
    # read frames

    # check if frame is None
    if frame is None:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break
    
    # do something with frame here
    
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)
    # Show output window

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# close output window

# safely close video stream.
stream.stop()
```

#### For VidGear `v0.2.0` and above: *(`y_tube` changed to `stream_mode`)*

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
import cv2

stream = CamGear(source='https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ', stream_mode = True, logging=True).start() # YouTube Video URL as input

# infinite loop
while True:
    
    frame = stream.read()
    # read frames

    # check if frame is None
    if frame is None:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break
    
    # do something with frame here
    
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)
    # Show output window

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# close output window

# safely close video stream.
stream.stop()
```

*[Code Source](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/camgear/usage/#using-camgear-with-youtube-videos)*

Comment: I tried this and got None frame, same as I got with pafy.

Comment: @ruckc This is an issue with the [`opencv-python`](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) library that doesn't support the `https` protocol due to lack of OpenSSL support in its FFmpeg build, more insight of this bug is [here](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/issues/14#issuecomment-494364397). The good news is that I recently pushed a [PR in opencv-python library](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/pull/229) that completely fixes this issue and has been merge by its author. So kindly wait few days when these bug-free binaries officially get available on PyPi to download. Goodluck.

Comment: @ruckc This bug is now fixed. Kindly update to latest opencv-python.

Comment: can you make this code switch to live...? 

 I mean, whenever I use it for a live stream that has been playing on YouTube for 20 mins, this code always starts reading from 00.00.

 I want it to start from 20 mins

Comment: @Mumbaikar007 Raise this issue on our GitHub repo. [here](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/issues/new/choose), we will surely work on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pip install pafy
#sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
import cv2, pafy

url   = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvyTx01ZcQQ"
video = pafy.new(url)
best  = video.getbest(preftype="mp4")
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(best.url)
while True:
    check, frame = capture.read()
    print (check, frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try this, works well on live streams too