# error: (-215:Assertion failed) error when trying to capture youtube video using pafy and openCv

Tags: python, opencv, youtube, pafy

I am trying to access youtube video using opencv and pafy. I followed the instruction given here [Is it possible to stream video from https:// (e.g. YouTube) into python with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555195/is-it-possible-to-stream-video-from-https-e-g-youtube-into-python-with-ope)
. But after following the instructions i got below mentioned error - 
**cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'**

```
import cv2 
import pafy

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p9VEKecHKI"
live = pafy.new(url)
stream = live.getbest(preftype="mp4")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream.url)

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
#cap.open(stream.url)

while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error which i got -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videoCapture.py", line 20, in <module>
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

When i give preftype="webm" at this line -

```
stream = live.getbest(preftype="webm")
```

i got below error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "videoCapture.py", line 11, in <module>
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream.url)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this
here we are first checking if we have a frame then only we are calling `cv.imshow('Video', frames)` otherwise it will come out of the loop.

```
while True:
    ret, frames = capture.read()

    # for preventing warning (-255 assertion failed)
    if ret:
        cv.imshow('Video', frames)
    else:
        break
    
    # for stopping the window manullaly
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2 
import pafy
import time

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p9VEKecHKI"
live = pafy.new(url)
stream = live.getbest(preftype="mp4")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream.url)

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
#cap.open(stream.url)

while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried with the suggestion which you have given but that one end up resulting in nothing. I mean i am not getting any result nor any error on my terminal. The problem with my code is it is not able to retrieve the video from the link. Thats why i am getting assertion error.

Comment: try minimizing all the windows to see the result, its in back. i too can't first then i minimize all , i found the frame.